# Hyperlink to PDF displays in web app when user is NOT logged in, returns 404 when user IS logged in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, hyperlink

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application.  On the main page there is a hyperlink which opens a PDF.  When a user **is not** logged in, the link works - displays the PDF.  When a user **does** log in, clicking the link returns a 404.

Coming behind someone's app and doing bug fixes so I'm not intimately familiar with the code. Any pointers or guidance would be much appreciated.

The link in question is:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="Files/link_to_pdf.pdf" target="_blank">Link to PDF</a></li>
</ul>
```

The page code up to the link is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10" />

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </head>
    <body id="@ViewBag.TripId">
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title">
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Survey")">
                            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/logo.png")" alt="The Logo" /><span>TEST COMPANY</span>
                        </a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            @if (ViewBag.TripId == null)
            {        
                <section class="sidebar" id="left">
                    <h3>Board Officers</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="test_link_1" target="_blank">Tech Dept</a></li>
                        <li>Managers</li>
                        <li><a href="test_link_2" target="_blank">Business Dept</a></li>
                        <li>Executive Council</li>
                        <li><a href="test_link_3"
                        <li>Quality Assurance</li>
                        <li><a href="test_link_4" target="_blank">QA</a></li>
                        <li>Administration</li>
                        <li><a href="test_link_5" target="_blank">Admin</a></li>
                        <li>Shipping & Receiving</li>
                    </ul>
                    <h3>More Information</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Files/link_to_pdf.pdf" target="_blank">Link to PDF</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
```

Comment: It might not solve your issue, but the first thing I'd try is <a href="@Url.Content("~/Files/link_to_pdf.pdf")"  just in case it's a relative path issue

Comment: Thank you for your response - I added that as you suggested and now it does work in debug, but it does not work on the live site - do you have any ideas as to why that might occur?

Comment: It's hard to say without being able to see it.  I'd check the source in a browser and see that the url that is generated in both environments is the same and that the folder on the server actually exists, if it does exist on the server and it's right, I'd start looking at permissions.  It might be that the app pool needs access to the folder or something like that